# Warning:io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.EllipticCurveProvider: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I can't generate my signed apk with json web token and proguard

```
Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.EllipticCurveProvider: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.jce.ECNamedCurveTable there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Exception while processing task javaio.10Exception: Please correct the above warnings first.
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 9.255 secs
1 error
3 warnings
See complete output in console
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/215), add the following rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` file :

```
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.bouncycastle.* { *; }
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.*

-keep class io.jsonwebtoken.** { *; }
-keepnames class io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }
-keepnames interface io.jsonwebtoken.* { *; }

-dontwarn javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
-dontwarn io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { * ; }
-keepnames interface com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

Comment: just adding * i think so